# "Process failed to start: Access is denied." When trying to convert tex/u3d to 3d PDF

Tags: miktex2.9

I am following the instructions on the page below:
http://www.cadforum.cz/cadforum_en/create-free-3d-pdf-output-from-any-cad-software-tip9972

I export my file from Sketchup (vrlm) then I import it in MeshLab and save it as u3d which creates a tex file as well

First of all I am a little bit confused, can't understand the difference between texworks and miktex-texworks, both files present in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64

Sencondly, and the most important when I press the green button (Run) I get the "procees failed to start: Access is denied." message

I must mention that I am admin and I have full rights over the MikTex folder and on my machine. I can't understand what is causing this. Any idea ?

Comment: even admins don't have access everywhere. But beside this you are not giving enough information.

Comment: PLease just ask what info you need in order to answer properly. Here is what I could think I should add: Win7, x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working after installing the file out of Program files (ex C:\Utils\MikTex2.9)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Utils\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Utils\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
```

It asked for a couple of packages to be installed and it produced an empty file. Now I have to deal with that